# Java regex if string container number

Tags: java, regex

so I am having trouble with regex. So I only want to detect if the string contain any number. match it if it does.

```
Case 1 "abc" -> false
Case 2 "165-45"  ->true
Case 3 "ab3b"  -> true
Case 4 "1231asdf" -> true
Case 5 "asdfasd123213" -> true
Case 6 "12-465"  -> true
Case 7 "ASDSAD" -> False
```

So far I got but failed case 3 and 4

```
if(query.matches("[0-9,-]+$")){
// contains a number

    System.out.println("match");
} else{
       // does not contain a number
    System.out.println("not match");
}
```

Comment: What does `String#matches(..)` do?

Comment: your regex should be `[0-9]+` with coma and minus, lines like `Some-Word` and `di it better, faster, stronger` will also be true.

Comment: @T.G ... No it won't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why bother with the comma, hyphen and end-of-input?

Also the `matches` method matches the whole `String`.

I would use something in the lines of:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(query).find());
```

Full example:

```
String[] queries = { "abc", // -> false
    "165-45", // -> true
    "ab3b", // -> true
    "1231asdf", // -> true
    "asdfasd123213", // -> true
    "12-465", // -> true
    "ASDSAD" // -> false
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
for (String s : queries) {
    System.out.println(p.matcher(s).find());
}
```

**Output**

```
false
true
true
true
true
true
false
```